# Bijective polynomials $f\in\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_n]$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, reference-request

Does it exist a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, of degree greater than $1$, that defines a one-to-one correspondence 
$f:\mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb Z$ or $f:\mathbb N^n\to\mathbb N$?

Are there methods to approach such questions at all?

---

See also [Conjecture about polynomials $f_n\in\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ defining bijections $\mathbb N^n\to\mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060811/conjecture-about-polynomials-f-n-in-mathbb-qx-1-dots-x-n-defining-bijection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known that the polynomial $f(n,m)=\frac{1}{2}(n+m)(n+m+1)+m$ defines bijection
$\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.

Reference: [Polynomial bijections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117390/polynomial-bijection-from-zxz-to-z).